# Why does GWT's RichTextArea implement HasInitializeHandlers?

Tags: gwt, richtextbox

...and what can I do with my RichTextArea *after* the onInitialize method has been called that I cannot do before?

N.B. This is a [cross-post](http://groups.google.com.au/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_frm/thread/736ff241971861db/c917705b730eda10?lnk=gst&q=RichTextArea#c917705b730eda10) from the GWT Google group, which produced no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `InitializeEvent` is fired just after the widget is attached to it's parent. Code that depends on the widget being attached to it's parents and thus the DOM shouldn't be executed before that point. 
The `RichTextArea` widget uses an `iframe` and this seems to be the cause that some functionality is only available after creation, also depending on the specific browser. I have no full list of all specific cases where you need to initialize code after the widget is attached. But one example specific the `RichTextArea` widget is if you want to set the focus on the widget the widget must be attached.

You could get the same behavior by extending the `RichTextArea` widget and overriding the `onLoad` method, but that requires creating a new class.